# can't linkify address for google maps for countries outside US

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to write a very basic app, that simply takes this address, for instance, in Israel, and linkifies it, so that when user touches it, it will open the google maps with the address, my code:

```
TextView israel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
israel.setText("Habarzel 34, HaBarzel Street, Tel Aviv, Israel")
Linkify.addLinks(israel, Linkify.ALL);
```

in xml:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="@string/israeli_address" />
```

Comment: not sure it can parse addresses out of the U.S.

Comment: ok, what makes you think that? i'm thinking the same thing to but can't find verification anywhere, thank you.

Comment: look further into this code https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/content/common/android/address_parser_internal.cc&sq=package:chromium

Comment: thank you. excellent reference.